# Adding data from form to List (or Set)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm developing web application using spring MVC. In form, I have a question and couple answers.

```
    <!-- Question-->
    <div>
        <label>Pytanie:</label> <input type="text"
            th:field="*{question.content.text}" placeholder="Wpisz tu pytanie"></input>
    </div>

    <!-- Answer1-->
    <div id="answer1" style="display: none;">
         <label>Odpowiedź:</label> <input type="text"
            th:field="*{answers}" placeholder="Odpowiedź">
        </input> 
        </div>
    <!-- Answer2-->
     <div id="answer2" style="display: none;">
        <label>Pytanie:</label> <input type="text"
            th:field="*{answer.content.text}" placeholder="Odpowiedź">
        </input>
<input id="addAnswerButton" type="button" value="+"
        onclick="counter++; addAnswer('answer');" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" />
```

The amount of answers can be different, I have simple script in JS to handle this:

```
var counter = 0;
    var numBoxes = 8;
    function addAnswer(showHideDiv) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv + counter);
        if (ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
        }
        if (counter == numBoxes) {
            document.getElementById("addAnswerButton").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Also, I have QuizForm class to wrap whole form:

```
public class QuizForm {

    @Getter @Setter
    private Quiz quiz;

    @Getter @Setter
    private Question  question;

    @Getter @Setter
    private ArrayList<Answer> answers;
}
```

And this is my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class QuizController {

    @Autowired 
    IQuestionService questionService;

    @Autowired 
    IContentService contentService;

    @ModelAttribute("quizForm")
    public QuizForm form(){
        return new QuizForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/quiz/new" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newQuiz(Model model) {
        return "add-quiz";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/quiz/save" }, method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String saveQuiz(QuizForm quizForm) {


        Content questionContent =quizForm.getQuestion().getContent();   
        contentService.save(questionContent);
        Question question = quizForm.getQuestion();
        question.setContent(questionContent);
        questionService.save(question);

        // ... ?

        //question.setContent(questionContent);

        //Content answerContent = new Content();

//      for(Answer string :quizForm.getAnswer()){
//          answerContent.setText(string);
//      }
//      questionContent.setText(quizForm.getQuestion());

        //quizService.save(quiz.get);
        return "add-quiz";
    }
}
```

Now, I don't know how should input in form looks like.Also how to handle saving array list using thymeleaf.
Any tip would be welcome!